# Insert statement to add data to the database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access, vba

I don't seem to find out what is wrong with my query. The values at the end are the name of the variables

```
Command.CommandText = (" INSERT INTO [TransfersAndAdditionalCourses]
               (TransferCourse1,TransferCourse2, TransferCourse3, 
               TransferCourse4, TransferCourse5, AdditionalCourse1,   
          AdditionalCourse2, AdditionalCourse3, AdditionalCourse4, AdditionalCourse5) 
          VALUES ('" & firstTransferCourse & ",' " & secondTransferCourse 
          & "," & thirdTransferCourse & " ', '" & fourthTransferCourse & " ','" 
          & fifthTransferCourse & " ', '" & firstAdditionalCourse & ", " 
          & secondAdditionalCourse & "',' " & thirdAdditionalCourse & "',' " 
          & fourthAdditionalCourse & "','" & fifthAdditionalCourse & "' ")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to me missing some single quotation marks.

Please try this:

```
Command.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO [TransfersAndAdditionalCourses]
           (TransferCourse1,TransferCourse2, TransferCourse3, TransferCourse4, 
            TransferCourse5, AdditionalCourse1, AdditionalCourse2, AdditionalCourse3,
            AdditionalCourse4, AdditionalCourse5)
    VALUES ('" & firstTransferCourse & "',' " & secondTransferCourse & "', '" 
               & thirdTransferCourse & " ', '" & fourthTransferCourse & " ','" 
               & fifthTransferCourse & " ', '" & firstAdditionalCourse & "', '" 
               & secondAdditionalCourse & "',' " & thirdAdditionalCourse & "',' " 
               & fourthAdditionalCourse & "','" & fifthAdditionalCourse & "' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Format the insert query and you will see the mistakes, you are missing the quotes in many places, also  the leading `(` and tailing `)` is not needed. It should look like something as

```
Command.CommandText = 
"
INSERT INTO [TransfersAndAdditionalCourses] 
(
    TransferCourse1,
    TransferCourse2, 
    TransferCourse3, 
    TransferCourse4, 
    TransferCourse5, 
    AdditionalCourse1,  
    AdditionalCourse2, 
    AdditionalCourse3, 
    AdditionalCourse4, 
    AdditionalCourse5
) 
VALUES 
(
    '" & firstTransferCourse & "', 
    '" & secondTransferCourse & "', 
    '" & thirdTransferCourse & "', 
    '" & fourthTransferCourse & "',
    '" & fifthTransferCourse & "', 
    '" & firstAdditionalCourse & "', 
    '" & secondAdditionalCourse & "',
    '" & thirdAdditionalCourse & "',
    '" & fourthAdditionalCourse & "',
    '" & fifthAdditionalCourse & "'
)"
```